# Display text in SearchView when iconified = true

Tags: android, searchview

I have a SearchView widget in my layout (not in action bar). The SearchView take all the screen widht (with padding).

I want to show a text besides the icons. I tried the queryhint, but it is only shown when clicking on the icon, when the searchview is not iconified...

How can I do something similar to playstore, Display icon + text and then when clicking on it, display the queryHint?